# Syntax error on Union query when using an Alias for subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I add an alias to the second subquery, I receive a syntax error in SQL Server. Why is this the case? Can someone explain? Here's the example of syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
> Incorrect syntax near 's'.

This is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 'Fail' [Status],fail_date[Date]
     FROM Failed) f
UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'Success' [Status],success_date[Date]
     FROM Succeeded) s
```

When removing the alias in the second subquery, it executes without any errors. Confused as to why an alias is allowed in the first subquery but not the second.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 'Fail' [Status],fail_date[Date]
     FROM Failed) f

UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'Success' [Status], success_date[Date]
     FROM Succeeded)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TL;DR answer is that table and subquery aliases have to exist inside a from clause.

I think it's actually your use of parentheses which is confusing you, because what you've done is actually try to alias a whole "select". The fact that the query happens to involve a union is not really relevant.

In the failing query, you have this kind of structure after the union:

```sql
(select * from MyTable) t; -- invalid, can't have an alias for a whole select.
```

Notice how the alias `t` here is outside the parentheses which surround the entire select statement. SQL is looking for a `from` clause:

```sql
... from (select * from MyTable) t; -- ok, the alias "t" will be used in the outer "from"
```

If the alias was inside the parentheses, it would be fine:

```sql
(select * from MyTable t); -- ok, alias is part of the from clause.
```

and of course it should be clear that this query doesn't actually need the parentheses:

```sql
select * from MyTable t; -- exactly the same as the previous query
```

So, in the case of your failing structure, you have:

```sql
select * from (some query) t -- alias is fine, it's used by the outer from clause
union all
(select * from whatever) u -- not ok, can't alias a whole select.
```

If you just remove the second set of parentheses, it's fine:

```sql
select * from (some query) t
union all
select * from whatever u;
```

Another way of understanding this is to understand that the "from" clause in the first part of the query "ends" at the union. The select after the union is an entirely new select statement with its own from clause:

```sql
select * from MyTable t1 -- this from clause is now done

union all -- we are starting a whole new select, it's not part of the above "from"

select * from MyTable t2
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this and breaking it down especially that part about not being able to alias an entire select statement. Understand it now & much appreciated. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You see it better in my last query

you union

```
SELECT *
FROM

(
    SELECT 'Fail' [Status],fail_date[Date]
    FROM Failed
) f
```

with

```
(
    SELECT 'Success' [Status],success_date[Date]
    FROM Succeeded
)
```

UNION doesn't need an alias, as you can see in the first union query

> ```
> CREATE TABLe Succeeded (success_date date)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe Failed (fail_date date)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM
>
> (
>     SELECT 'Fail' [Status],fail_date[Date]
>     FROM Failed
>
>
> UNION ALL
>
>     SELECT 'Success' [Status],success_date[Date]
>     FROM Succeeded
> ) s
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Status | Date
> :----- | :---
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM
>
> (
>     SELECT 'Fail' [Status],fail_date[Date]
>     FROM Failed
> ) f
>
> UNION ALL
> (
>     SELECT 'Success' [Status],success_date[Date]
>     FROM Succeeded
> )
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Status | Date
> :----- | :---
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM
>
> (
>     SELECT 'Fail' [Status],fail_date[Date]
>     FROM Failed
> ) f
>
> UNION ALL
>
>     SELECT 'Success' [Status],success_date[Date]
>     FROM Succeeded
>  
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Status | Date
> :----- | :---
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca1d3eb98577ac37b006eae7f9fa7f7c)*